# strange bar behaviour in coreplot

Tags: iphone, ios, indexing, core-plot, cptbarplot

I am having a very bizarre situation with barPlot. Firstly, even when the data is null, it gives me two large barplot at indexes 1 and 2, which i can't work out where they are coming from?

[image]

And secondly, when I then call the reloadDataIfNeeded/reloadData method, it then seems to place the bars in the middle (it appears identically each time)

[image]

Ill post the code below, but it seems odd that when i don't call reload data, it gives me bars already on the barplot. - it never calls:

```
 -(NSNumber *)numberForPlot:(CPTPlot *)plot field:(NSUInteger)fieldEnum recordIndex:(NSUInteger)index {
```

it just places bars on the barplot. When i reload the data it calls that method, and despite the indexes being correct, it still misplaces the bars?

Comment: Which other plot datasource methods are implemented in your datasource?

Comment: I had quite a few other graph datasource methods in my datasource, but originally it wasn't calling it and hence the two bars still remains a mystery to me. However, i sorted the problem out. The datasource methodology was wrong.

Comment: Originally i used:

 if ((fieldEnum == CPTBarPlotFieldBarTip) && (index < [_averageDataValuesMultiple count])) {
if ([plot.identifier isEqual:_nameComingThrough]) {
[_averageDataValuesMultiple objectAtIndex:index]);
return [_averageDataValuesMultiple objectAtIndex:index];
                
} else if ([plot.identifier isEqual:PAR]) {
return [_averageOfPar objectAtIndex:index];
}
}

However, the correct method was:

Comment: switch ( fieldEnum ) {
            case CPTBarPlotFieldBarLocation:
return [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInteger:index];
break;
case CPTBarPlotFieldBarTip:
if ([plot.identifier isEqual:_nameComingThrough]) {
return [_averageDataValuesMultiple objectAtIndex:index];
} else if ([plot.identifier isEqual:PAR]) {
return [_averageOfPar objectAtIndex:index];
} }

Comment: You need to add this as an answer and accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this problem I used:

```
 switch ( fieldEnum ) {            
case CPTBarPlotFieldBarLocation: return [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInteger:index]; break; 
case CPTBarPlotFieldBarTip: 
if ([plot.identifier isEqual:_nameComingThrough]) { 
return [_averageDataValuesMultiple objectAtIndex:index]; } 
else if ([plot.identifier isEqual:PAR]) { 

return [_averageOfPar objectAtIndex:index]; } 
}
```